# Terraform Lambda in VPC allow network access for HTTP Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform for the first time and got a little lost in the configuration and I am facing this issue with my Lambda Function that should be able to do a simple HTTP request to google.com or swapi.com ( or whatever other external API ).
In my case in my linkedin callback I need to use the linkedin api.
Here is some part of my configuration:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 5.21.0"
    }

    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = ">= 3.3.0"
    }

    archive = {
      source  = "hashicorp/archive"
      version = ">= 2.2.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.0"
}


provider "aws" {
  region     = var.region
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "main-vpc"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "main_igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "route-table-main" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.main_igw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "main-route-table"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat_eip" {
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gateway" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_eip.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_a.id

  tags = {
    Name = "nat-gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "route-table-nat" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.nat_gateway.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "nat-route-table"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "main_sg" {
  name        = "main-sg"
  description = "Terraform SG"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 3306
    to_port     = 3306
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24" ]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main_subnet_a" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2a"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main_subnet_b" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2b"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "main_subnet_c" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.3.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2c"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main_subnet_nat_gateway_a" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.4.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main_subnet_nat_gateway_b" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.5.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2b"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main_subnet_nat_gateway_c" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.6.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2c"
}


resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db_subnet_group" {
  name        = "db_subnet_group"
  description = "My DB subnet group"

  subnet_ids = [
    aws_subnet.main_subnet_a.id,
    aws_subnet.main_subnet_b.id,
    aws_subnet.main_subnet_c.id
  ]

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association-a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.main_subnet_a.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route-table-main.id

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association-b" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.main_subnet_b.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route-table-main.id

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association-c" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.main_subnet_c.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route-table-main.id

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association-nat-gateway-a" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_a.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route-table-nat.id
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association-nat-gateway-b" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_b.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route-table-nat.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association-nat-gateway-c" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_c.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.route-table-nat.id
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec" {
  name               = "lambda-exec"
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_sns_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess"
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_auth" {
  type = "zip"

  source_dir  = "../${path.module}/lambdas/auth"
  output_path = "../${path.module}/lambdas/auth.zip"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "lambda_auth" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket.id

  key    = "auth.zip"
  source = data.archive_file.lambda_auth.output_path

  etag = filemd5(data.archive_file.lambda_auth.output_path)
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "auth_test" {
  function_name = "auth-test"

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket.id
  s3_key    = aws_s3_object.lambda_auth.key

  runtime = "nodejs18.x"
  handler = "index.test"

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_auth.output_base64sha256

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn

  environment {
    variables = {
      RDS_DATABASE_NAME = var.database_name
      RDS_DATABASE_HOST = aws_db_instance.cyrannus_database.address
      RDS_DATABASE_USER = aws_db_instance.cyrannus_database.username
      RDS_DATABASE_PASS = aws_db_instance.cyrannus_database.password
    }
  }

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main_sg.id]
    subnet_ids         = [aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_a.id, aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_b.id, aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_c.id]
  }

  timeout = 60
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "auth_linkedin_callback" {
  function_name = "auth-linkedin-callback"

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket.id
  s3_key    = aws_s3_object.lambda_auth.key

  runtime = "nodejs18.x"
  handler = "index.linkedinCallback"

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_auth.output_base64sha256

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn

  environment {
    variables = {
      RDS_DATABASE_NAME = var.database_name
      RDS_DATABASE_HOST = aws_db_instance.cyrannus_database.address
      RDS_DATABASE_USER = aws_db_instance.cyrannus_database.username
      RDS_DATABASE_PASS = aws_db_instance.cyrannus_database.password
      LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID = var.linkedin_client_id
      LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET = var.linkedin_client_secret
      LINKEDIN_REDIRECT_URI = "${aws_apigatewayv2_stage.dev.invoke_url}/auth/linkedin/callback"
    }
  }

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main_sg.id]
    subnet_ids         = [aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_a.id, aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_b.id, aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_c.id]
  }

  timeout = 60
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "auth_test" {
  name = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.auth_test.function_name}"

  retention_in_days = 14
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "auth_linkedin_callback" {
  name = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.auth_linkedin_callback.function_name}"

  retention_in_days = 14
}
```

I've tried to use NAT Gateway as presented in some tutorial but I am a little lost, AWS Console interface seems to do a lot of things by default and I am not sure what I am missing.

I've managed for example to create an EC2 that is in the VPC to access a RDS that is in the same VPC and gave it network access with IGW and I am able to to curl commands an added a simple phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed a NAT Gateway in a subnet that has a route to the NAT Gateway. That's a circular reference. This subnet does not actually have a route to the Internet, so the NAT Gateway will not actually work.

- Your NAT Gateway should be in a subnet that has a route to the Internet Gateway.
- Your Lambda function should be in a subnet that has a route to the NAT Gateway.

Comment: Indeed I am stupid and blind.
I just had to change the line in the nat_gateway to use a subnet from the main_route that is attached to the IGW:
  
subnet_id     = aws_subnet.main_subnet_a.id

instead of 

subnet_id     = aws_subnet.main_subnet_nat_gateway_a.id.

The lambdas were set correctly to use the subnets from the NAT Gateway.

Comment: I am facing a different problem now that my Lambda is using subnets for Nat Gateway, I can't access the RDS anymore. My db is in Internet Gateway "aws_db_subnet_group.db_subnet_group" and "aws_subnet.main_subnet_a" is used in my EC2 in order to allow me to create that phpmyadmin.

I am not sure how I should work with those 2. I don't want to create another lambdas within RDS subnet just to interact with the database, is there any other way?
@MarkB

Comment: That DB issue is almost certainly a security group thing, not a subnet thing. Your security group(s) are kind of a mess. You have a single security group assigned to everything, which is really bad practice. And you are using CIDR Blocks instead of security group IDs for ingress rules, which is another bad practice. You need to add an ingress rule to the database server's security group, that allows ingress on port `3306` from the security group assigned to the Lambda function, or from the CIDR blocks of the Lambda function's subnets.